# Playing Red Alert on LAN

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert

Is it possible to play the original Red Alert on LAN? I've looked up various ways, although I was never able to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to play older games, like Red Alert, via LAN connections on newer operating systems you'll need to emulate IPX connections between the machines. There are a few ways to accomplish this.

For DOS games you're in luck as [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Connectivity) comes with this support natively. Simply start the ipx server on one machine `ipxnet startserver [UDP port]` and then connect to it on the rest of the machines `ipxnet connect <IP> [UDP port]`

For Windows based games you can use something like [Kali](http://www.kali.net/) which will give you a fairly robust interface, or something like [ipxemu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipxemu/files/ipxemu-1.0.0/) or [ipxwrapper](http://www.solemnwarning.net/ipxwrapper/) which will trick the games into thinking they are connected via IPX.

Comment: Ok but let's say you have an ipx server running on some machine (IP address `x.x.x.x`). Upon opening Red Alert, what steps do you take to play over IPX?  screenshots would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible according to the [manual](http://redalert1.com/files/ramanual.pdf) and the hundreds of hours I spent playing it. Note that early Red Alert (and Command & Conquer) games need the IPX-protocol to play multiplayer games, which isn't supported by many current operating systems.

Comment: Is there a way to play it on Windows 7?

Comment: That sounds like a new question

Comment: There is an unofficial patch which fix the LAN play by switching it to udp protocol. The full game patcher / installer from http://funkyfr3sh.cncnet.org/ includes it.